# Traceback when building an exrm release of a Phoenix app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, exrm

After SCP-ing my Phoenix app dir from my Macbook to my Fedora VM, I try to build a production exrm release but an exception is raised:

```
==> Building release with MIX_ENV=prod.
==> Generating relx configuration...
==> Generating sys.config...
==> Generating boot script...
==> Performing protocol consolidation...
==> Conform: Loading schema...
==> Conform: No schema found, conform will not be packaged in this release!
==> Generating release...
===> Missing beam file megaco_flex_scanner <<"/usr/lib64/erlang/lib/megaco-3.17.3/ebin/megaco_flex_scanner.beam">>
===> Missing beam file 'Elixir.Access' <<"/home/me/lartbot/rel/lartbot/lib/elixir-1.1.1/ebin/Elixir.Access.beam">>
===> Missing beam file error_handler <<"/home/me/lartbot/rel/lartbot/lib/kernel-4.1/ebin/error_handler.beam">>
===> Missing beam file erl_anno <<"/home/me/lartbot/rel/lartbot/lib/stdlib-2.6/ebin/erl_anno.beam">>
===> Missing beam file cow_cookie <<"/home/me/lartbot/rel/lartbot/lib/cowlib-1.0.2/ebin/cow_cookie.beam">>
===> Missing beam file cowboy_middleware <<"/home/me/lartbot/rel/lartbot/lib/cowboy-1.0.4/ebin/cowboy_middleware.beam">>
===> Missing beam file 'Elixir.Phoenix.HTML' <<"/home/me/lartbot/rel/lartbot/lib/phoenix_html-2.3.0/ebin/Elixir.Phoenix.HTML.beam">>
===> Missing beam file 'Elixir.Poison' <<"/home/me/lartbot/rel/lartbot/lib/poison-1.5.0/ebin/Elixir.Poison.beam">>
===> Missing beam file 'Elixir.Plug' <<"/home/me/lartbot/rel/lartbot/lib/plug-1.0.3/ebin/Elixir.Plug.beam">>
===> Missing beam file 'Elixir.Mix.Phoenix' <<"/home/me/lartbot/rel/lartbot/lib/phoenix-1.0.4/ebin/Elixir.Mix.Phoenix.beam">>

02:59:36.683 [error] Error in process <0.10938.0> with exit value: {{badmatch,{error,enoent}},[{rlx_prv_assembler,rewrite_app_file,2,[{file,"src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl"},{line,215}]},{lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1237}]},{ec_plists,'-local_runmany/3-fun-0-',3,[{file,"src/ec_plists.erl"},... 


** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :enoent}
        src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl:215: :rlx_prv_assembler.rewrite_app_file/2
        (stdlib) lists.erl:1237: :lists.map/2
        src/ec_plists.erl:753: anonymous fn/3 in :ec_plists.local_runmany/3
    src/ec_plists.erl:900: :ec_plists.handle_error/3
    src/ec_plists.erl:764: :ec_plists.local_runmany/3
    src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl:152: :rlx_prv_assembler.copy_app_directories_to_output/3
    src/rlx_prv_assembler.erl:58: :rlx_prv_assembler.do/1
    src/relx.erl:286: :relx.run_provider/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1261: :lists.foldl/3
    src/relx.erl:266: :relx.run_providers/1
    lib/exrm/utils.ex:94: ReleaseManager.Utils.relx/5
```

I'm completely new to Erlang, Elixir, and Phoenix so I haven't really got the faintest idea how to troubleshoot this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some talk at https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm/issues/107 that this is fixed by using a different install of Erlang. That didn't look like a good approach for me. So on the advice of others I tried running with

```
mix release --verbosity=verbose
```

That got me more information, including the following error:

```
===> Provider (resolve_release) failed with: {error,
                                                {rlx_prv_release,
                                                 {failed_solve,
                                                  {unreachable_package,
                                                   phoenix_live_reload}}}}
```

So in my case phoenix_live_reload was causing the problem. I removed phoenix_live_reload from the application and deps functions of my mix.exs (I didn't want to include that in production anyway) and then it successfully built the release for me.

Comment: Will check this out later when I get some time and report back. Gut tells me this is the right direction though, because I've seen some other errors that looked like they were related to live reload.

Comment: I'm thinking I may have had some stuff lingering in the copy on my server. I nuked the SCP-d dir, only rsync-d instead while --exclude deps/ --exclude rel/. Then set MIX_ENV=prod in my environment and ran mix do deps.get, compile, then mix release. The release builds, but I've now moved onto a newer more differenter error when running the build. Cheers!